# add column based on "last name, first name" that returns "first name last name" to Database in Laravel/React App

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a search page in a Laravel/react App that uploads a CSV file with several fields, one of which is "last name, first name".  The search doesn't return any results when a user searches for "first name last name".  In other words, if you search for "Smith, John" you get a result, but not if you search for "John Smith".

In the Laravel controller the method used is updateOrCreate to upload the CSV and create or update a table in a MySQL DataBase.  I'm thinking it would be good to make that method add a new column that changes "last name, first name" into "first name last name".

The React view maps different fields from the uploaded csv file.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Better still to have 2 seperate columns on the table

Comment: you could just make a virtual column first_last as `(case instr(last_comma_first,', ') when 0 then last_comma_first else concat_ws(' ', substr(last_comma_first,instr(last_comma_first,', ')+2), substring_index(last_comma_first,', ',1)) end)`